# How to refactor multiple 'app.post' with next() to route.post()

Tags: node.js, express

I am refactoring some code from my main file to a subdirectory using node's router. At the moment I use:

**main.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// ... stuff
app.post('/api/authorize', (request, response, next) => {
  // some promise chain, that makes an external API-call and extracts data
  next();
})

app.post('/api/authorize', (request, response, next) => {
  // verify a JSON webtoken
})
```

Now I try to refactor this to a different file

**main.js**

```
// ... stuff
app.use( require('./api/authorize') );
```

**api/authorize.js**

```
let express = require('express')
let router = express.Router();

// ... stuff
router.post('api/authorize', (request, response, next) => {
  // some promise chain, that makes an external API-call and extracts data
  next();
})

router.post('/api/authorize', (request, response, next) => {
  // verify a JSON webtoken
})

module.exports = router;
```

The second `router.post('api/authorize')` seems to overwrite the first one. So the first part isn't being run.

How can I achieve the same behavior I have in the initial `main.js` in `api/authorize.js`?

Comment: And in the first version didn't it overwrite the first one?

Comment: Yes. It may have to do with the fact that `app` is an instance of `express` and router is an instance of `express.Router`.

Comment: I checked the second version, and it doesn't overwrite the first. I added a console.log to the first one, and it logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that behaviour when I try.

And also you can simplify your authorize routes like this:

In main.js define a common path for this route:

```js
app.use("/api/authorize", require("./routes/authorize"));
```

In the authorize route, now we don't need to repeat `/api/authorize`.

```js
let express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();

router.post("/", (request, response, next) => {
  // some promise chain, that makes an external API-call and extracts data
  console.log("First");
  next();
});

router.post("/", (request, response, next) => {
  // verify a JSON webtoken
  console.log("Second");
  response.send("Second result");
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I send a post request to the `/api/authorize` I see that first one also is called since it output these in the console:

```
First
Second
```

Comment: Thx. I actually tried it out again. I forgot to add a `/` before one of those routing paths in my real code. For some reason that feels unnatural to me, I guess. So it was a typo on my side. Also thanks for the small improvement, I ll use it :).